# java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB Problem, in recursion android studio

Tags: android

I am currently building a minesweeper game in android studio.
I am now building a function that basically makes the numbers show ("bomb") when you "mine"(click on one of the squares)
basically, the algorithm is:
the function is getting the index of the square as parameters ,when pressing that square(imageView)
if you press on a square- it will be revealed. if it is a square with 0 mines nearby it will also be revealed and will also do the same function on all of the squars nearby. I did this function with recursion but im getting an error "java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB".
I might be because the recursion is calling itself too much or that it is an endless loop. anyways, I dont know how to solve that. please help
(code down here:)

```
public void bomb(int i,int j)
{
   if(i>-1&&i<8&&j>-1&&j<10)
    {
        board[i][j].setRevealed(true);
        if(board[i][j].getNumOfMinesNearby()==1)
        {
            board[i][j].setPicture("@drawable/one");
            board_xml[i][j].setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
        }

        if(board[i][j].getNumOfMinesNearby()==2)
        {
            board[i][j].setPicture("@drawable/two");
            board_xml[i][j].setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
        }
        if(board[i][j].getNumOfMinesNearby()==3)
        {
            board[i][j].setPicture("@drawable/three");
            board_xml[i][j].setImageResource(R.drawable.three);
        }
        if(board[i][j].getNumOfMinesNearby()==4)
        {
            board[i][j].setPicture("@drawable/four");
            board_xml[i][j].setImageResource(R.drawable.four);
        }
        if(board[i][j].getNumOfMinesNearby()==0)
        {
            board[i][j].setPicture("@drawable/zero");
            board_xml[i][j].setImageResource(R.drawable.zero);
            bomb(i-1,j+1);
            bomb(i-1,j);
            bomb(i-1,j-1);
            bomb(i,j+1);
            bomb(i,j-1);
            bomb(i+1,j+1);
            bomb(i+1,j);
            bomb(i+1,j-1);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `anyways, I dont know how to solve that. please help` same way anyone here will help, by reading through your code, line by line and looking at it to see if it makes sense. if you cant get a solution with recursion, don't use it. use breakpoints, logs, read through it - learn to debug your code

Comment: @a_local_nobody For most of us, it take years, before we are able to learn to effectively debug our code. The best way to learn it, is to watch a more experienced developer actually doing it in practice.

Comment: @kgiannakakis i agree, but often times people just post complete solutions here with the idea of "find my problem, thanks" and that doesn't help anyone to really learn. often times, people are just lazy, but in a lot of cases people don't even know how to debug, most people don't even know about stack traces, which is frustrating for everyone. being able to debug your own code often adds more value than just having someone tell you what's wrong. either way, my comment wasn't meant to be rude to anyone, it was meant to be constructive :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite recursion problem.  Let's say you have a 0 at board[0][0] and board[0][1].  When the user presses at [0,0] it will go into the recursive case.  That will call it on [0,1].  Which will call it on [0,0].  Etc.  You need to alter the algorithm so it doesn't call bomb if you have already called it on that index.

Comment: got it,thank you!

Comment: Just for future knowledge-  the way you figure out what's going on here is to take a look at the stack trace, and look for a loop.  If you see a loop of the same functions repeating endlessly, you need to break it somehow.  In cases where its one function looping endlessly, have the function print out its parameters at the top, and print out when it exits at the bottom.  Look for something that is being called again with the same parameters to find the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are creating an infinite loop. When you call your function for `i,j` it will trigger invocation for `i+1,j-1`, which in turn invoke the function for `i-1,j+1`, which is `i,j` (where you've started from).

You need to modify your code, so that each cell is only visited once. Recursion should also be avoided. Better to do it in a for loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<ni;i++) {
  for(int j=0;j<nj;j++) {
     // process cell here
  }
}
```